# not able to boot into windows 10 after installing kali in dual boot mode

Tags: windows-10, uefi, kali-linux, grub2, dualboot

I have installed kali linux 5.4.0 with qindows 10. But from grub i am not able to boot into win10. If I click on win10, it is coming back to grub. If I change boot mode to "UEFI" then it is not booting into grub, directly booting into win10.

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of GRUB available: one for legacy booting and one for UEFI booting. Typically on a UEFI enabled computer you would install the UEFI version of GRUB (in Ubuntu the package is called grub-efi) and shim. Shim is needed if you enable secure boot.

When you reinstall Kali Linux make sure that you are in UEFI only mode.

Comment: just discovered this. problem is too many brands have an issue with UEFI when installing Kali - for some reason, attempting to do so will screw up the video (garbled screen) as soon as you try to install it, so you have to go back to legacy to install (meaning dual booting is only possible after you switch bios settings).

Comment: If anyone knows of a way to force Kali to boot in UEFI even if it was installed via legacy mode, that would help thousands of IT people with Lenovo laptops.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved. I reinstalled kali in UEFI mode.